# How to list only not-named volumes with docker

Tags: docker

`docker volume ls`
shows all volumes, both named and unnamed

Is there an option to filter out and show only unnamed volumes?

Answer (score 1):

All volume are named, not all are named by you.

From the man, this is the only filter allowed for the ls command over volumes:

```
dangling (boolean - true or false, 1 or 0)
driver (a volume driver's name)
label (label=<key> or label=<key>=<value>)
name (a volume's name)
```

I suggest you to use label or to name all your volumes.